# I have frequent connect/disconnect hardware sounds when playing games, how can I fix this?

Tags: windows-7, gaming

The connect/disconnect sounds are frequent but random, and only when I am playing games.  Sometimes the sound is accompanied by the screen turning black for about one second, but not always.  Here is what I have tried so far:
  Nothing shows up in the event viewer associated to the sounds.  I ran a game in window mode, nothing shows up on the task bar as connecting or disconnecting.  I updated my video card driver.  I ran dell diagnostic, no problems detected.  However, I noticed when it was testing the video card, the sounds/screen blanking did occur.  I opened the case and cleaned out the minimal dust and made sure everything was tightly connected.

Windows 7
Dell Studio XPS 7100
AMD Phenom II X4 945 Processor 3 GHZ
8GB Ram
64-bit OS
AMD Radeon HD 6670 video card

The only things connected to the USB ports are the mouse and keyboard.

I don't know what to do to fix this problem, any advice appreciated.

I am using separate speakers.

Comment: What cable do you use?
Do you hear through your monitor (via HDMI) or through separate speakers?

Comment: Don't play the game with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try getting updated drivers.  Typically I find that this type of problem is due to interference with out-of-date drivers clashing.

Comment: I updated the video driver.  Can you tell me what other drivers might need updating?

Comment: sound drivers since you are heard stuff though your speakers.  In general, I'd make sure ALL drivers are up-to-date.  A driver perhaps holding off an interrupt too long or a buggy driver can cause all sorts of weird unepxected things to happen.

Comment: Just a follow up on this... it turned out to have nothing to do with the drivers.  I updated every one that I could find.  It turned out to be the monitor.  Replaced the monitor, no more connect/disconnect sounds or black screens.  Tada!  Still don't know why.